# Getting Error on Subscriber Preview with AMPScript Code in the email

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, email-template

I am getting an error on the subscriber preview section after testing the AMPScript with test DE records in Marketing Cloud.
Below is my code:

```
%%[
    set @Phone = [Phone]
    set @Name = [First Name]
    set @Email = [Email]
    set @Contactid = attributevalue("Contact id")
    set @orderrows = LookupRows("Testing_DE_Name","Contact id", @Contactid)
    set @orderRowCount = rowcount(@orderrows)
    if @orderRowCount > 0 then
    for @i = 1 to @orderRowCount do
        set @row = row(@orderRowCount, @i)
        set @Contact_id = field(@row,"Contactid")
        set @ServAddress = lookup("Oppotunity Salesforce DE","Service_Custom_Address__c","Contactid",@Contact_id) 
        set @Appt_Date = lookup("Oppotunity Salesforce DE","Quote_Appointment_Date__c","Contactid",@Contact_id)
        set @Advisorname = lookup("Oppotunity Salesforce DE","Opportunity Owner ID field","Contactid",@Contact_id) 
]%%
<!-- Display something here? -->
%%[next @i]%%

%%[ else ]%%
No User Details were found
%%[ endif ]%%

%%[
    if not empty(@Name) then
        set @Greeting = Propercase(@Name)
    else        
        set @Greeting = "Homeowner"
    endif
]%%
```

Here is the details of the error I am getting:

[image]

Please Help me with this!

Thanks
Adam

Comment: Try to replace this line `set @row = row(@orderRowCount, @i)` to `set @row = row(@orderrows, @i)`. The `@orderrows` is a row set not `@orderRowCount` a row count

Comment: Thank you @DucLe. It worked  :)